# This/last/next year/month/week in German

Tags: usage, time

I wonder if "in diesem Jahr" is fully interchangeable with "dieses Jahr" when used as an adverbial modifier of time.  And can one also say, "in letztem Jahr" and "letztes Jahr" and "in nächstem Jahr" and "nächstes Jahr"?

Can one also do this with weeks, months, seasons and days of the week?  For instance, can one say, "in letzter Woche" and "letzte Woche", "in letztem Monat" and "letzen Monat", "in letztem Januar" and "letzten Januar", "in diesem Winter" and "diesen Winter", "in nächstem Montag" and "nächsten Montag"?

Comment: Interessanterweise kann man *in nächstem Montag* gar nicht sagen, sondern nur *am nächsten Montag*. Bitte in Fragen keine Begrüßungs- und Abschiedsfloskeln. Danke.

Answer (score 11):

> in diesem Jahr
>
> <s>in letztem Jahr</s> i**m** letzte**n** Jahr
>
> <s>in nächstem Jahr</s> i**m** nächste**n** Jahr

But yes, these are fully interchangeable with *dieses Jahr* resp. *letztes Jahr* resp. *nächstes Jahr* in everyday speech and writing. In highbrow writing, rather not.

You wonder about the **m** and **n** mixup? That's because *dieser/diese/dieses* is a demonstrative pronoun and does not require an article, while there's the article *dem* hidden inside the *im*. *Letzten* and *nächsten* work as adjectives, so the adjective declination kicks in.

> <s>in letzter Woche</s> in **der** letzte**n** Woche
>
> <s>in letztem Monat</s> im letzte**n** Monat
>
> <s>in letztem Januar</s> im letzte**n** Januar
>
> in diesem Winter

Same.

> <s>in nächstem Montag</s> **am** nächste**n** Montag

Days require **an** rather than **in**:

> am ersten Tag der Ferien
>
> am 1.1.
>
> am Weihnachtstag

Special cases:

> an/zu Weihnachten *(any of the three days)*
>
> zu Ostern *(any of the four days)*
>
> zu Pfingsten *(any of the two days)*
>
> zu Silvester
>
> an Neujahr